# sqlite closest number search

Tags: javascript, sqlite

Restricted to only using javascript and sqlite..

This option uses a custom sqlite function but unfortunately i cannot use this as I am using appcelerators titanium which only uses javascript...

I have a table of towns and cities with the following format:

```
id
place_name  
county  
country 
grid_reference  
easting 
northing    
latitude    
longitude   
postcode_area   
type
```

I know this question has been half asked in lots of different ways but I can't really find a straight forward answer.

If i had a set of coordinates such as:

```
latitude : 51.452295,
longitude : -0.678864
```

How would i be able to find the closet place_name from the table above based on the provided longitude latitude?

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much answers the question - it isn't possible.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/146721/finding-closest-result-based-on-long-lat